# How to connect a mobile application to Metamask or other Ethereum wallet

Tags: node.js, angular, ethereum, solidity

I was wondering for the educational purposes I am trying to make an ethereum mobile app using solidity for my smartcontract, angular for the mobile app, backend nodejs and using infura to migrate the server from ganache to infura to a ethreum test server. But i am having trouble understanding or finding a way to make it work.

What I mean by that is how can I use metamask (or are there anything similar) that can sing the transacion and manage your ether for mobile app since my app will not be a webapp. ive been searching all over the web but i could not find anything related to that.

Comment: I also suggest you write your questions in professional English, because writing hard to read English makes your questions hard to read, discouraging readers to answer to your question. For example, names and letter I should be capitalised. I can give you recommendations to learn English grammar if you need help.

Comment: thank, you very much i will keep that in mind. I am new to stackoverflow and english is not my first language but any feedback on how I can do a better question is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WalletConnect mobile linking](https://docs.walletconnect.org/mobile-linking) to interact between mobile apps and mobile wallets.